# @RequestAttribute return null for own attribute created by AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop

I would like to read the request attribute in the controller that I added in spring AOP. But is still return null. Maybe I read this data incorrectly? Maybe I can't use annotation for that?

Aop:

```
@Around(value = "putMappingPointcut(putMapping)", argNames = "joinPoint,putMapping")
public Object checkPutHeaders(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, PutMapping putMapping)    throws Throwable {

final RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(requestAttributes)).getRequest();
final String apiKey = request.getHeader(API_KEY);


 final String company = apiKeyProviderService.getCompanyBy(apiKey);
 request.setAttribute("company", company);

 return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Controller:

```
@PutMapping("/accounts")
public Company authenticate(@RequestAttribute(name = "company", required = false) String company,
                            @RequestBody Authentication authentication) {
....

}
```

If I add `HttpServletRequest` to my controller and call `getAttribut("company")` I receive correct code for company.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The method invocation is build **before** the method is invoked, at that point it is still `null`. It is being set upon invocation (due to your `@Around` aspect). Ditch the aspect and write a filter which does this.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the answer. But one more question, can I use other AOP annotation for that case?

Comment: No. Because SPring MVC builds the invocation before it is invoked, so no AOP isn't going to solve this for you.

Comment: You are right, so I create WebMvcConfigurer bean and class that implements `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, thanks for the explanation